# spring security with active directory with binddn and password

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, lda

Want to integrate Spring Security with LDAP. After sone research, i find out below code:

```
    @Override
       public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider();

                  .ldapAuthentication()
    
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                    .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword1");
   }
```

When I checked with the LDAP team they told me they don't have a password attributes they suggested to use binddn and bindpaswd but I am not sure how to configure this?
.
any ref link or code snippet will help

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security supports both Password authentication and [Bind authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap-bind).

Here is an example of Bind authentication configuration

```
@Bean
BindAuthenticator authenticator(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
    BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
    authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] { "uid={0},ou=people" });
    return authenticator;
}

@Bean
LdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(LdapAuthenticator authenticator) {
    return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator);
}
```

You can also check out this [LDAP sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/ldap) for a complete application.

Comment: Can you refer to some documentation for a better understanding of the Ldap API provided by Spring?
1. what I wanted is how to map any organizational structure in spring search?
2. How to apply USER_DN_SEARCH_BASE_DN?
3. How to apply USER_DN_SEARCH_FILTER?
4. How to apply LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH_BASE_DN?
5. GROUP_SEARCH_FILTER?
6. GROUP_NAME_ATTRIBUTE?
7. LDAP_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY?
8 Make it INSECURE?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11430047/eleftheria-stein-kousathana)

Can you refer to some documentation for a better understanding of the Ldap API provided by Spring? 1. what I wanted is how to map any organizational structure in spring search? 2. How to apply USER_DN_SEARCH_BASE_DN? 3. How to apply USER_DN_SEARCH_FILTER? 4. How to apply LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH_BASE_DN? 5. GROUP_SEARCH_FILTER? 6. GROUP_NAME_ATTRIBUTE? 7. LDAP_TLS_SKIP_VERIFY? 8 Make it INSECURE?